# Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a ProductViewModel that converts a DTO (Product) at runtime.

```
public class ProductViewModel : IViewModel {

    public ProductViewModel() {
        Categories = new List<CategoryViewModel>();
    }

    #region DTO Helpers

    public ProductViewModel(Product p) {
        this.ID = p.ID;
        this.Name = p.Name;
        this.Price = p.Price;
        Categories = new List<CategoryViewModel>();
    }

    #endregion


    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<CategoryViewModel> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

I've used this code with LINQ2SQL before and it's worked, but now with entity framework it doesn't:

```
        var products = (from p in db.GetAll()
                        select new ProductViewModel(p));
```

I get this error:

```
Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities
```

**Can anybody help explain/fix this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var products = (from p in db.GetAll()
               select new ProductViewModel{
                   ID = p.Id,
                   ....
               });
```

Comment: That's not very DRY since I'm going to have to do that snippet about 45+ times, Why does it not work via the ctor? is there an alternative?

Comment: LINQ needs a parameterless constructor because it wants to use collection initialization (the `{}` brackets). You can have additional class constructors, but LINQ will not use them. If the snippet needs to be reused, why not put in in a reusable function?

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve all details from single entity use this

```
Context.Set<your entity>().AsQueryable();
```

Comment: Could you elaborate please? I'm trying to parse X amount of Product objects into X amount of ProductViewModel objects.